# Different storyboard localization per target

Tags: ios, xcode, internationalization, interface-builder, xcode7

I have a project with 3 targets. Each target needs to suppport only one language, but the language is not the same for each target.
Currently I have

- Target 1 (es)
- Target 2 (es)
- Target 3 (pt)

Most of my strings are in a Localizable.strings file, and I simply target a different file for each target. However, a number of strings are in my storyboards. My problem is that it does not seem possible to create different storyboard localization files for each target. If I change the targeting of the portuguese file, the targeting of the spanish file changes automatically.

A possible solution is to duplicate each Storyboard for each target, but this won't scale well as the number of tagets grow. I could also modify all the text with NSLocalizedString in each ViewController, but this seems tedious and error prone.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: might want to put an xCode tag on this question as the answer is very likely some sort of xCode setting

Answer (score 9):

## Shared Storyboard across targets

While [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33749062/218152) is the preferred approach, you can assign different Storyboard **localizations** to different targets, while sharing the **same** Storyboard across all targets.

**Prerequisites:**

Follow this instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33749062/218152).

**Concept:**

You want to have the `Main.storyboard` in each target, but a different  `Main.strings` in each target. Additionally, you do not want all localizations to be available in each target.

To achieve this, you must manipulate the `.lproj` directly, a process which is hidden when merely using the File Inspector.

**Step by step:**

1. Create all the pieces by following the steps in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33749062/218152).
2. From any target, remove the `Main.storyboard`. Of course, select *Remove Reference* to keep the storyboard around.
3. In the Finder, locate Base.lproj. Drag and drop `Main.storyboard` back to your project, and **select** every target.
4. In the File Inspector, ensure that the languages are **not** selected, and that you are still using `Localizable Strings`.
   [image]
5. In the Finder again, locate `en.lproj`, `es.lproj`, `fr.lproj`, etc. Notice that they each contain a version of `Main.strings`. Drag these .lproj (the entire directories) back into your project. This time, do **not** select any target
6. One last time, in File inspector, associate each `Main.strings` to the desired target. Repeat for each `.strings`.
   [image]

**Conclusion**

By decoupling the `.lproj` from the `.storyboard` in the Project Navigator, you can associate files and targets freely.

**Demo:**

See it at work using a French target, on a device with language set to Français in the Settings:

[image: French example on iPhone 4]

---

► Find this solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/SwiftArchitect/SO-33694785) and additional details on [Swift Recipes](http://swiftarchitect.com/recipes/#SO-33694785).

Comment: I did this, and it did not work. While tha .strings files are added to the correct targets, they are not being read by the storyboard. The contents of the .strings are never used; I just see whatever text is in the original storyboard.

Comment: This may happen if you are targeting for a language not available on the device. Make sure you go to **Settings** on the device, and pick the language you are targeting for. I have added a screen shot & an actual Xcode project for you to verify that my post is accurate, and that the technique I outline has been verified and tested.

Comment: But then the target is not supplying only one language. This answer is a bit better than the other one in that each target supports the base language plus the target language instead of all languages, but it still does not solve the original problem.

Comment: *each target supports the base language plus the target language instead of all languages*: isn't it exactly what you are trying to do? You must use a Base if you do not want to duplicate the storyboards. By definition, "localized" mean "run in the preferred language". If you want your app to run in, say, Esperanto, regardless of the OS, then you cannot use any of the localization support ; you must create your App in Esperanto. This is when the post compilation scripts and the plist manipulation scripts come into play.

Comment: No, I am sorry if the question reads that way. Each target must be available in exactly one language.

Answer (score 7):

## Shared localizations across targets

1. *Assuming you already have multiple languages in your project*, in the *Project Navigator*, select your storyboard (say *Main.storyboard*)
2. In the *File Inspector*, under **Localization**, add *English*. Pick **Localizable Strings** which is the default. This will create a `Main.string` for each language, and share your Storyboard across all languages.

   [image: Create a Main.strings]
3. Merely clicking that checkbox in step 2. will **add** a `Main.string (English)` for that language, specifically for that `Main.Storyboard`. Pay special attention to the new hierarchy, these are **not** `Localizable.strings` but `Main.strings`, derived from `Main.storyboard`:

   [image: New localizations per Storyboard]
4. Localize in each language file to your heart content.

For example, starting with a `UILabel` which message was in *Esperanto*, it will appear in English when the device runs in *English*:

```
/* Class = "UILabel"; text = "Tiu mesaĝo estas en Esperanto"; ObjectID = "acC-pA-eMt"; */
"acC-pA-eMt.text" = "This message is in English";
```

---

**Start here to add multiple languages to your project:**

In the event you need to add more languages, follow these steps:

1. In the *Project Navigator*, select your Project
2. In the *Project and Target List*, select, once again, the Project

   [image: Pick the project]
3. Select the *Info* tab
4. Under **Localizations**, keep **Use Base Internationalization** *(unless your UI itself must change across languages)*
5. Click **+**, pick a new language. In the dialog presented to you, select every Storyboard you want to have multiple localizations for.

   [image: Pick Storyboards to be localized]

If you missed Storyboards at Step 5. you can simply add a new language to that a storyboard by following the steps in *Assuming you already have multiple languages*.

Comment: This makes each target support all languages. But as I said, each target needs to only support one language.

Comment: Once the `Main.strings` exist, you can pick the ones you need on a per-target basis. Multiple targets create multiple executables (one per language in your example), which is very different from a single, multiple language app. In essence, you are not localizing your app, you are creating multiple apps.

Comment: No. At least in XCode 7, if I add the portuguese Main.strings to Target 3 , all other Main.strings are added automatically to the same target. Even if that would somehow work, since to get ot that point I had to add localiazions to my project, all my tarets will be amrked as having localization, when they don't. And this will be a problem when I publish my app.

Comment: Good point. I have created http://stackoverflow.com/a/33791181/218152 to address the `.lproj` concerns and clearly address the target associations.

Comment: any idea how can have a different Main.strings for each target? in other words having one storyboard but have different Main.Strings file for each language. @SwiftArchitect

Comment: I dont remember. but, I think I couldnt find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

All you need: to make common xcode workspace for your app, then to create a duplicates of main xcodeproj file for your set of languages and make different targets for all of them, also then you can set language for individual project settings in new xcodeproj's. Also you easy can tune build phase 'Copy Bundle Resourses' and others. I use this method. If you have a Xcode's crash during adding project in workspace - open project with Xcode, rename it and rename or duplicate targets (I think same names cause this issue).